# Silverlight to RIA Service to Business Objects Causes Build Errors

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I've went through the basic tutorials associated with Silverlight and Ria Services and I am now trying to branch out to a model I have used before.

I have a Silverlight project that I want to use Ria Services with.  Unlike the tutorials for Ria Services that I've seen, I'm wanting to have my Domain Services to use Repository objects in a Business Object (DLL) project that holds my domain entities (created using EF).

Here's an example snippet of a domain service I'm working with:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class ContactService : DomainService
{
    public List<Contact> ContactSearch(string lastName)
    {
        ContactRepository rep = new ContactRepository();
        return rep.SearchByLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

Contact and ContactRepository are in my Business Objects project.  ContactRepository queries EF for the Contact Entities.

When I build, I get the following error:

> The entity
>   'SilverlightCRM.BusinessObjects.Contact'
>   does not have a key defined. Entities
>   exposed by DomainService operations
>   must have must have at least one
>   property marked with the KeyAttribute.

If I change the entity generated code to decorate the `Contact.ContactID` property with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Key()` attribute as described [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/05/silverlight-ria-services-and-your-business-objects.aspx), I get another build error in my `<projectname>.g.cs` file of my project containing my domain service.

> Type of Namespace 'Data' does not
>   exist in namespace 'System' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

Since the `<projectname>.g.cs` file is autogenerated on build, just commenting out a line doesn't work and I have System.Data as a project reference.

What am I doing wrong here? I would think that I'd be able to use this model of organizing aspects of my solution but do I have to change things if I want to use Ria Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I discovered was that I had to have my Ria Service inherit from LinqToEntitiesDomainService instead of just Domain Service since the types being passed were Entities from EF.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're referencing the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations dll from the RIA services folder (it has a version of 99.0.0.0).

Comment: After doing that, I'm now able to build the 2 projects separately; however, if I build the full solution, I get the error still.  Thoughts? (besides just build separately :-) )